# How exactly does abstract method returns the desire type without being override?

Tags: java, android

I recently was looking through the android documentation for SurfaceView and I found that to get the actual surface you have to do the following:

```
SurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface()
```

The documentation for the surface holder is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html

Now a SurfaceHolder is return from getHolder() which then you can call getSurface() on that holder to get a surface. Now if you check the getSurface() method, you will see it is an abstract method. I thought abstract method are meant to be override and then it can return the desire type.

However, this here give you a reference to an interface which is the SurfaceHolder and then you call getSurface() which is an abstract method which means there is no point where the method is being override.So how exactly does the code that check and return the appropriate surface get called from an abstract method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of abstract methods is correct.

The thing you are missing is that getHolder() returns a *concrete* implementation. A concrete subclass of its abstract base, or in your case, a concrete implementation of an interface. The function is declared as returning the base class/interface, but any derived class can be returned in reality. This is one of the major forms of polymorphism:

```
 Base getThing () { ... }
```

Can return a Base, or any subclasses / implementation of Base.

Further reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

The concrete implementation being returned to you is probably some internal non-public thing, who knows (I'm not familiar with the Android api myself), but it doesn't matter to you. You don't need to know exactly what is returned to you. You only need to know that it implements SurfaceHolder or whatever.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now but the thing that still concerns me is that what exactly is the abstract base that surfaceHolder is implementing from? Usually, when android extend an interface it usually tells you in the documentation. For instance, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html. As you can see the view is implementing multiple interface with is abstract. So I can understand if a view is consider to be an interface.

Comment: @JustCurious SurfaceHolder is the base interface. The concrete implementation being returned to you is probably some internal non-public thing, who knows. But the point is that it doesnt matter to you. You don't need to know exactly what is returned to you. You only need to know that it implements SurfaceHolder or whatever. If you really want to find out just to satisfy your cuiosity, though, you can use reflection to print the class name and hierarchy, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/.

Answer (score 0):

What actually gets returned at run time is an object that implements `SurfaceHolder`. You'll have to look elsewhere in the runtime libraries to figure out what concrete object type is returned.